# Linq: how can I speed up the string comparison inside for a RemoveAll predicate?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string> listToTemove
list.ForEach(e => e.Persons.RemoveAll(m => listToTemove.Any(m1 => m1 == m.Name)));
```

`Persons` is a `List<Person>` and `Person` has a property `Name`

The operation lasts 70 seconds. The list has 30 elements each of which has a list of 400 elements for a total of 21000 string comparisons.

Most of `Persons` are removed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having it as a `List<string>` use a `HashSet<string>`:

```
HashSet<string> itemsToRemove = new HashSet<string>(listToTemove);
e.Persons.RemoveAll(m => itemsToRemove.Contains(m.Name));
```

A single `Contains` on `HashSet` is an `O(1)` operation whereas on a `List` it is `O(n)`. Lowering the total of an `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`.

Also instead of removing you can maybe select only those you want:

```
e.Persons = e.Persons.Where(m => itemsToRemove.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Now it takes 1 ms :O

Comment: @Revious - glad it helped :)